# How to replace specific links in a webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a chrome extension script that scans a webpage for specific clickable links, and replaces them with other links if they match.

Here is what I have since updating this post with a minimum reproducible example (updated farther below) but it only works for function rewritePage1 which is based on the answer I received specifying outerHTML. Thank you!

```
 var matcher = "alias text"
      var newText = "true text";
      function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
      //var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector), i;
    
      for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        if (!elems[i].childNodes.length)
          elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace(matcher, newText);
    }
```

Updated test webpage:

```
    <html>
    <h1>test webpage</h1>
    <p>alias text</p>
    <a href="https://yahoo.com">alias test 1</a>
    <p><a href="https://bing.com">alias test 2</a></p>
    </html>
```

Updated manifest file:

```
 {
      "name": "OzWizard3",
      "action": {},
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "version": "0.1",
      "description": "demo to replace specific urls on a webpage.",
      "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "ozwizard3.js"
  }
}
```

Updated main script testing both answers:

```
//chrome extension runs when activated by clicking extension icon.
//lookup a url in a database or dictionary as key.
//If found a match on the page, replace it with the value of that key.

function rewritePage1() {
let urlLinksToChange = 'https://yahoo.com';
let replaceWithThisElement = `<a href="https://google.com" style="color:red">Replaced!</a>`;
let linksToChange = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="${urlLinksToChange}"]`)
linksToChange.forEach(l => {
     l.outerHTML = replaceWithThisElement;
});
}

function rewritePage2(){
  var matcher = "https://bing.com"
  var newText = "https://yahoo.com";

  function replaceText(text, newText) {
      // get all links with specific urls
      var links = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="${text}"]`);
      // loop through all links
      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
          // get the href
          var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
          // replace the href
          links[i].setAttribute('href', newText);
      }
  }
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: rewritePage1
  });
});
```

Comment: May you share a [mcve]? The example doesn't show how it's used.

Comment: Updated with an example of how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace whole elements, not just its URLs, then for that, we can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

For example if we want to replace all links that start with `https://meta.` and replace with `<a href="https://google.com" style="color:red">Replaced!</a>`. We would do this:

```
let urlLinksToChange = 'https://meta.';
let replaceWithThisElement = `<a href="https://google.com" style="color:red">Replaced!</a>`;
let linksToChange = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="${urlLinksToChange}"]`)
linksToChange.forEach(l => { 
     l.outerHTML = replaceWithThisElement;
});
```

The difference between innerHTML vs outerHTML is that innerHTML modifies the internals of the node, while outerHTML modifies the whole node itself.

[image: https://ravisah.in/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-innerhtml-and-outerhtml]
*Source: https://ravisah.in/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-innerhtml-and-outerhtml*

Comment: This is a great answer with more details that I was not aware of! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code through which you can replace the specific urls.

Html

```
link: <a href="https://bing.com">bing</a>
link: <a href="https://bing.com">bing</a>
link: <a href="https://bing.com">bing</a>
```

Script

```
var matcher = "https://bing.com"
var newText = "https://google.com";

function replaceText(text, newText) {
    // get all links with specific urls
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="${text}"]`);
    // loop through all links
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        // get the href
        var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
        // replace the href
        links[i].setAttribute('href', newText);
    }
}
```